# Is it best practice to use router.navigate in Components or Services?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I don't know the philosophies underlying angular, especially regarding testing, well enough to know if I should prefer to use `router.navigate()` in Components or Services.

For example, suppose you have a `LogInComponent` that manages your log in form and an `AuthService` that handles talking to the server. When a user successfully logs in, you want to redirect them from the log in screen to the home page of the application. Is it best to do that in `LogInComponent` or `AuthService`?

Comment: There is no solvable question here... merely calling for opinion.

Comment: @TimMcNamara best practices are sometimes opinion and sometimes overwhelmingly majority and common sense dictates what is best. I think this is the latter and has a "correct" answer.

Comment: "Based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise".
I could give soooo many references:
http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PresentationDomainDataLayering.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture

From Angular 2 itself:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: Imho There's HUGE a difference between asking someone's opinion for an specific use case and asking for a Best Practice or Industry Standard of how to solve a problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Definitely Component, the Services are only supposed to bring the data you want, it should not know anything about the Presentation, whether its a Single Page Application, a simple static pages, a hybrid or native app, let alone how you navigate between them, that way you can change this later and you can reuse your whole services package.

Comment: Services are there not for the only purpose of bringing data, they could share any logic including some navigation scenarios which are common through the app. So it depends on a particular app.